# httpd - if clause does not trigger when file exits

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost, apache2.4

I have a virtual host in httpd config with several *ProxyPass* and *Rewrite* rules and I want to trigger a redirect if a file exists on filesystem.

```
<If "-f '/tmp/somefile'">
Redirect temp "/" "https://another.server.com/somepath/index.html"
</If>
```

This config works on other httpd (2.4 on xubuntu), but not on the one I need to (2.4 on CentOS). The *apachectl configtest* verifies the config OK.

The */tmp/somefile* is readable by apache. But when I *touch* the file, the condition is, I guess, still false, because no redirect happens.

I am not able to find any error in logs.

Is there anything I am overlooking and should take care of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is not in the _if_ but in the _Redirect_. If I omit the _if_, httpd still does not redirect my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the precedence of *ProxyPass* in the same *VirtualHost*. Because I did not find any solution how to make the *ProxyPass* conditional, I have created the second config file and I am replacing them and reloading httpd.